# Updating mysql values from '0' to '1'?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a mysql query to fetch all user reviews on my website which are pending to be either approved or deleted by the user.

I have a basic file structure:

Reviews.php which pulls the mysql results and the function file approve_review.php.

The new reviews come through fine in the mysql query but when i try and approve or delete a review nothing happens, I get no error or anything.

When approve is clicked it is suppose to UPDATE the table ptb_reviews.approved from '0' to '1' and if delete is clicked the same applies, it would update the review from '0' to '1'.

(I have only included the approve code for this purpose as they would both in effect be the same with a approve being set to delete)

I am using review_id so that it knows which review to approve or delete and session so that only the user can approve or delete them.

Can someone please have a look and see if they can see a way of getting it to work?

Reviews.php:

```
<?php
            $pending_set = get_pending_reviews();
            while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($pending_set)) {


    ?>

            <div class="prof-content-pend-reviews" id="reviews">
                 <div class="pend-review-content">
                 <?php echo "{$reviews['content']}"; ?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="message_pic">
                 <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" src=\"data/photos/{$reviews['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";?>

                 </div>

                 <div class="forum-text">
                 <?php echo "Posted by {$reviews['display_name']}"; ?> <?php echo "".$age." days ago"; ?>
              </div>

              <a href="includes/approve_review.php?review=<?php echo $reviews['review_id']; ?>"><div class="approve"></div></a>
               <a href="includes/delete_review.php"><div class="delete"></div></a>


                 </div>

                 <? }  ?>
```

approve_review.php:

```
 function approve_review($review_id, $user) {
                            global $connection;
                global $_SESSION;
                            $query = "UPDATE ptb_reviews
                                        SET approved='1'
                                        WHERE id=$review_id";
                mysql_query($query, $connection);


                    }


        <?php
        require_once("session.php"); 
        require_once("functions.php");
        require('_config/connection.php');
        approve_review ($_GET['review_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
        header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/reviews.php');
        ?>
```

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. (Consider what happens if I edit the `appprove_review.php` query string to say `review_id=id` or even `review_id=1;DROP+TABLE+ptb_reviews`.)

Comment: why do you have a <?php tag when you're writing PHP already in approve_review.php? is that how it actually is? in that case that would be causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

> i get no error or anything.

That's probably because you aren't checking for errors.

Every time you call database API functions, you need to check the return value.  Most of the functions return `false` if there was any error, and then you need to call another function to check what *type* of error it was, error message, etc.

Example:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your function 'approve_review' needs 2 parameters. But nothing is done with the second parameter.

Anyway,

First of all, for security's sake:

```
$review_id = (int) $_GET['review_id']; 
    // Just this, is a great security enhancement. Forces the variable to be int (like all id's are). 
    // You can also check if its a numeric by doing
if (is_numeric($review_id)){
    // continue with the update query
} else {
    // something fishy is going on..
}
```

You may want to look at [PDO, prepared statements to prevent any SQL injections.](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Your query should look like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE ptb_reviews SET approved = 1 WHERE id = '$review_id' LIMIT 1";
// Using a LIMIT 1 is also a good practice. It limits the updates to 1 only in case of a hack.
```

To debug your query, you should just echo your query, to see if it's proper SQL format.

```
echo $query;
die();
// See what is really sent to MySQL
```

You should also use:

```
if (!mysql_query($query, $connection)){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

To see if your query even gets executed successfully and if there are any errors (why it is not being set to reviewed = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just show errors inline:

```
mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Which should reveal any issues.